# GCC/G++ equivalent of ldconfig -n

Tags: gcc, g++, ld

When I create my own non-standard path for library files (say, ~/lib) I can run `ldconfig -n ~/lib` and this directory is added to the list of locations ld uses to search for non-standard libraries.

Is there a similar switch for GCC/G++ (or an appropriate gcc/++ config manager) *related to include directories*, and if so, what? I'm aware the `-I` flag will include non-standard directories, butI'd rather not have to go through all my projects and have to add all forms of magic to the makefiles to make them work -- and then find that these changes are (of course) non-portable to any other system this code is built on (with collaborators, etc), so editing the makefile isn't really an option....

Edit: Note that my ignorance assumes this solution is gcc/++ only. I'm happy for any solution, however, so if there's a method that abuses some property of ldconfig or whatever, I'm not adverse to it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, just do `man gcc`. You'll need `-L <path>` flag if you are willing to change the Makefiles. There's also a solution similar to `ldconfig` - to use `LIBRARY_PATH` env. variable.

Similarly, there's `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` and `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CPATH` which are declaring a list of directories to search for header files.

Comment: Sorry, my question probably needed a bit of clarification - this is specifically regarding includes, rather than linking. -L has to be used on a per-link basis (and thus isn't an option I can add to a makefile that's shared between multiple developers). Same goes for -I, which is why I'm looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with `include` files, apart from modifying the gcc/g++ *source code* and recompile it.

The best alternative is adding an `alias` to your enviroment (if using bash) like:

```
alias gcc="gcc -Idir1 -Idir2 -Idir3"
alias g++="g++ -Idir1 -Idir2 -Idir3"
```

or creating an ad-hoc script.